# Is this a homeomorphism?

Tags: general-topology, product-space

Suppose you have a cartesian product of spaces $\prod_{\alpha\in\mathcal{A}}X_{\alpha}$  in the product topology.

Choose any $\alpha\in\mathcal{A}$ . Is the following a homeomorphism of a subspace of $\prod_{\alpha\in\mathcal{A}}X_{\alpha}$  with $X_{\alpha}$?

For each point $p_{\alpha}\in X_{\alpha}$  choose one point $(x)\in\prod_{\alpha\in\mathcal{A}}X_{\alpha}$  with $x_{\alpha}=p_{\alpha}$ . Let's call the set of all these points $P$ .

Consider the projection map $\pi_{\alpha}$  restricted to $P$. It is continuous, open and one-to-one, thus a homeomorphism between $P$ and $X_{\alpha}$.

Answer (score 4):

No, that construction will not in general give you a subspace of $X$ homeomorphic to $X_\alpha$. A simple counterexample is the graph of the function

$$f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R:x\mapsto\begin{cases}
0,&\text{if }x<0\\
1,&\text{if }x\ge 0\;:
\end{cases}$$

it’s not connected, so it can’t be homeomorphic to $\Bbb R$. (Here $|A|=2$, and both factor spaces are $\Bbb R$.)

What **does** work is to pick any one point $x\in X$ and let

$$Y=\big\{p\in X:p_\beta=x_\beta\text{ for all }\beta\in A\setminus\{\alpha\}\big\}\;;$$

then $Y$ is homeomorphic to $X_\alpha$. In the case of the product $\Bbb R^2$ in the example above, for instance, this construction gives you horizontal lines and vertical lines in the plane, which are all homeomorphic to $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Would this work https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1886926/837396

Answer (score 2):

Here is a counterexample: Let $X_1=X_2=\Bbb R$. Thus $X_1\times X_2=\Bbb R^2$ with the metric topology. For $p\in X_1,\ p\ge0$ choose the pair $(p,1)$ and for $p<0$ choose $(p,0)$. Then the projection map $\pi_1$ restricted to $P$ is not a quotient map (hence not open).

Comment: I have trouble seeing why the projection (restricted) is not open.  The projection maps unrestricted are open.  So take an open set $U\subseteq P$.  Then $U=V\cap P$ for some $V$ open in $\prod$ .  $\pi_\alpha \mid P (U)=\pi_\alpha \mid P (V\cap P)=\pi_\alpha \mid P (V)\cap \pi_\alpha \mid P (P)$ gives an open set in $X_\alpha$?

Comment: First of all, you can deduce that $\pi_1|_P\ $ cannot be open, because this would make $\pi_1|_P\ $ a homeomorphism, but $P$ is not connected while $X_1$ is. To prove it directly, take $V=\Bbb R\times (\frac12,\frac32)$. Its intersection with $P$ is $[0,\infty)\times\{1\}$, and this projects onto $[0,\infty)$ which is not open in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Ok good example.  But why not $\pi_\alpha \mid P (U)=\pi_\alpha \mid P (V\cap P)=\pi_\alpha (V)\cap \pi_\alpha (P)=$ (open set in $X_\alpha) \cap X_\alpha$

Comment: The last equality is false, because $\pi_1(V\cap P)$ is not equal $\pi_1(V)\cap\pi_1(P)$.

Comment: Ok I forget something.  It is true that intersections, unions, complements play well with the preimage operation, but I guess not with image.

Comment: That's right. $\cap$, $\cup$ and complements are preserved by the preimage operator, but the image operator usually only preserves unions. You always have $f(A\cap B)\subseteq f(A)\cap f(B)$, and you have equality for all subsets iff $f$ is injective.