# Need examples of different functions for homeomorphism in product topology

Tags: general-topology, advice

I am looking for a bunch of examples of homeomorphisms in the finite product topology.

I need it for a proof

Someone mentioned my question was vague .

The theorem is:

Let n>1 and let $X_1,...,X_n$ be topo. spaces
Then each $X_i  $is homeomorphic to a subspace of
the product space

I asked for different functions after seeing this post:

[Homeomorphism in product and box topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1886926/homeomorphism-in-product-and-box-topology)

Can the idea in this post be used to prove the theorem I am trying to prove.

I saw a proof of it in **Topology Without Tears** .So I
did one version based on it

I want to do a different one. That is why I am asking.

The more interesting the better
Thanks

Comment: A very vague question.

Comment: Look up the Invariance-of-Domain Theorem

Comment: Then homeomorphisms are local .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but here are some examples:

(1) Consider $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ with prime factorization $n=\varepsilon p_1^{v_1}\dots p_k^{v_k}$, where $\varepsilon \in \{1,-1\}$ and $v_i \in \mathbb{N}$. By the chinese remainder theorem, we have a ring isomorphism
$$
\Phi : \mathbb{Z}/n \stackrel{\sim}{\longrightarrow} \prod_{i=1}^k \mathbb{Z}/(p_i^{v_i}).
$$
We can, however, consider the quotient topology $\tau$ on $\mathbb{Z}/n$, induced by the canonical projection $\pi : \mathbb{Z} \twoheadrightarrow \mathbb{Z}/n$. We see that $(\mathbb{Z}/n,\tau)$ is a discrete topological space, because $\mathbb{Z}$ is discrete. Moreover, the space $\prod_{i=1}^k \mathbb{Z}/(p_i^{v_i})$ is discrete as a product of discrete spaces. It follows that $\Phi$ is a homeomorphism.

(2) Let $f:X\to Y$ me a map between topological spaces. Denote with
$$
\Gamma(f) := \{ (x,f(x)) \mid x \in X \} \subset X \times Y
$$
the graph of $f$, equipped with the subspace topology of the product topology on $X \times Y$. Let $p_X : X \times Y \to X$, $(x,y) \mapsto x$ denote the projection in the first component. Then, it can be shown that
$$
p_X|_{\Gamma(f)} : \Gamma(f) \to X, \qquad (x,y) \mapsto x
$$
is a homeomorphism if and only if $f$ is continuous.

I hope this was helpful!

Comment: I haven’t learn quotient topology yet.